# Synchronize UICollectionView with UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I'm working on a UI that has a UICollectionView which is horizontally scrollable with a UITableView below it:

[image]

My goal is that whenever I scroll within the TableView, the CollectionView will move at exactly the same speed and the same amount/direction as the Tableview did and vice versa.

So I somehow need to connect them. I played around with getting the `myTableView.contentOffset.y` and putting this value in the CollectionView     `myCollectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: offset, y: 0), animated: true)`.

However this function would need to be called all the time in shortest possible intervals and its not really synchron nor smooth and fast.

Is there any other possibility to achieve this?

Thankful for any input!

Comment: Are your collectionView cells a constant width, and your tableView cells a constant height?

Comment: Yes, they are constant width/height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"this function would need to be called all the time in shortest possible intervals"* is not really true. You only need to synch the scrolling when the tableView (or collectionView) is *scrolled*.

To do that, implement `scrollViewDidScroll`.

But, you'll have several issues to deal with...

First, unless your rows are the same height as your cells are wide, you can't use `.contentOffset.y` directly.

For example, if your rows are 50-pts high, and your cells are 100-pts wide, when you've scrolled down 10 rows the `.contentOffset.y` will be 500. If you set `.contentOffset.x` on your collectionView to 500, it will only scroll 5 cells instead of 10.

So, you'd need to use the offset **percentage** -- not too tough to calculate.

However...

Based on the image you posted, you're showing about 13 rows and about 3 cells. As you scroll down, converting to percentage offset, when Row 2 is at the top Cell 2 will be at the left edge. When Row 3 is at the top Cell 3 will be at the left edge. And so on... which is great.

Until you've scrolled ***all the way down***. Now, if you have a total of 100 rows, the top row will be row 87, and the visible cells in your collectionView will be 87, 88 & 89... no way to get to cells 90 through 100.

Here is some example code that shows synched scrolling *and* shows the problem when you get to the bottom of the table (using 50 data items):

```
class CvTvViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var myData: [String] = []
    
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue,
        .systemPink, .systemYellow, .systemTeal,
    ]
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var tableViewActive: Bool = false
    
    var cvCellWidth: CGFloat = 120
    let tvRowHeight: CGFloat = 50
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // fill myData array with 50 strings
        myData = (1...50).map { "Data: \($0)" }
        
        let cvl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        cvl.itemSize = CGSize(width: cvCellWidth, height: 100)
        cvl.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        cvl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        cvl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: cvl)
        
        tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.rowHeight = tvRowHeight
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
            
        ])
        
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.register(MyCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cvCell")
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.register(MyTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tvCell")
        
    }
    
}

extension CvTvViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        tableViewActive = scrollView == tableView
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        if tableViewActive && scrollView == tableView {
            let pctOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y / (CGFloat(myData.count) * tableView.rowHeight)
            let xOffset = (CGFloat(myData.count) * cvCellWidth) * pctOffset
            collectionView.contentOffset.x = xOffset
        }
        if !tableViewActive && scrollView == collectionView {
            let pctOffset = collectionView.contentOffset.x / (CGFloat(myData.count) * cvCellWidth)
            let xOffset = (CGFloat(myData.count) * tvRowHeight) * pctOffset
            tableView.contentOffset.y = xOffset
        }
        
    }

}

extension CvTvViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tvCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTVCell
        c.label.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        return c
    }
}

extension CvTvViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cvCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCVCell
        c.contentView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.item % colors.count]
        c.label.text = myData[indexPath.item]
        return c
    }
}

class MyTVCell: UITableViewCell {
    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

class MyCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

It will look like this on launch:

[image]

and like this after scrolling a bit:

[image]

and like this when we've scrolled all the way down:

[image]

---

**Edit** if you want to be able to scroll all the way to the last row / item (which can be a little disconcerting, as it's not what users are accustomed to, but...), add this code:

```
// track the table view frame height and
//  collection view frame width
var tvHeight: CGFloat = 0
var cvWidth: CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // we only want to call this if
    //  the tableView height or
    //  the collectionView width changes
    if tvHeight != tableView.frame.height || cvWidth != collectionView.frame.width {
        tvHeight = tableView.frame.height
        cvWidth = collectionView.frame.width
        
        var edge = tableView.contentInset
        edge.bottom = tableView.frame.height - tvRowHeight
        tableView.contentInset = edge

        edge = collectionView.contentInset
        edge.right = collectionView.frame.width - cvCellWidth
        collectionView.contentInset = edge
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughts. 
Im aware of the issue that I need to offset a percentage, that's why (for now) I simply changed the height of my TableViewCells to the width of the CollectionView. My biggest issue is that the movement is not really simultaneously, there's always a slight delay when using the `scrollViewDidScroll` function and im wondering how to get rid of it or if there's any better way to handle it.

Comment: @user16071310 - do you see a delay in the sample code I posted?

Comment: Indeed I have zero lag when using your code! Have to go over my code to figure out what's the issue. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: One more question: Why you've put in the `tableViewActive`-variable in the `scrollViewDidScroll` function as you already figure out what View was scrolled in the if-statement? I cannot see any difference even after removing it. Thanks again!

Comment: @user16071310 - when you set the `contentOffset`, it will generate a call to `scrollViewDidScroll`. If you remove the check for `tableViewActive` and add a couple `print(...)` statements in the `if` blocks, you'll see they're both executing, regardless of which one you're dragging. May not notice it visibly, but we only want the block to run if the user is scrolling that object.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks once again!

Comment: If someone has the same issue: found a way to get to the remaining cells in the CollectionView by setting an inset to the CV in the Identity Inspector: click the plus button to add an user defined runtime attribute. Select `Rect` as its type and `contentInset` as its key path. `Reference: {{top, left}, {bottom, right}}`

Comment: @user16071310 - I edited my answer to include implementing `.contentInset` for both the table view and collection view.